# Replacing specific parts of a matrix

Tags: matrix, manipulate, replacement, list-manipulation

I have `lensp=101; pid=0.5212; qid=1-pid; e1=0;`

Let's say I have a matrix such as `newp = Table[e1, {i, lensp}, {j, lensp}];`

I am trying to replace the elements of the matrix such that for each row `i`, the `Min[i+1,lensp]`th column`=pid`, and the `Max[i-1,1]`th column`=1-pid`. So each row should have two non-zero elements and the rest are zeros. [The Matlab code is `newp(i,min(i+1,lensp))=pid` and correspondingly]. I have tried many times in *Mathematica* but without success. I have tried

```
For[i = 1, i <= lensp, i++, 
  For[j = 1, j <= lensp, j++,
    newp = ReplacePart[newp, newp[[i, Min[i + 1, lensp]]] = pid, 
                               newp[[i, Max[i - 1, 1]] ] = qid]
  ]
]
```

but it does not work.

Comment: Please properly format your question. As a not-so-novice user you should already be able to do that yourself. In case you don't know how, see [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/formatting)

Comment: Sorry about that. I would properly format my question when asking next time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `lensp = 9`,

```
newp1 = SparseArray[{{i_, j_} /; j == Min[i + 1, lensp] -> 
     pid, {i_, j_} /; j == Max[i - 1, 1] -> qid}, {lensp, lensp}];
newp1 // MatrixForm
```

or

```
newp2 = ReplacePart[newp, {{i_, j_} /; j == Min[i + 1, lensp] -> 
     pid, {i_, j_} /; j == Max[i - 1, 1] -> qid}];
newp2 // MatrixForm
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thank you very much. This definitely works.

Answer (score 3):

With a smaller matrix:

```
lensp = 11; pid = 0.5212; qid = 1 - pid; e1 = 0;
newp = Table[e1, {i, lensp}, {j, lensp}];
```

One can change the elements with a straightforward assignment `newp[[i, j]] = new value`:

```
Do[newp[[i, Min[i + 1, lensp]]] = pid, {i, lensp}];
Do[newp[[i, Max[i - 1, 1]]] = 1 - pid, {i, lensp}];

MatrixForm[newp]
```

[image]

But seeing the form of the output, it's better to use `SparseArray` and `Band` to construct a matrix from scratch:

```
sa = SparseArray[{Band[{1, 2}] -> pid, Band[{2, 1}] -> 1 - pid, 
  {1, 1} -> 1 - pid, {lensp, lensp} -> 1 - pid}, {lensp, lensp}]

MatrixForm @ sa
```

> the same as for `newp`

```
sa == newp
```

> True

Comment: Thank you very much. This definitely works.